# Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns MySQL JDBC Eclipse Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert the contents of a .csv file to a database table using a java program in eclipse. However, I am getting the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

I did look into similar posts, but could not figure out the solution for my code. Any idea how I can resolve the issue ?

## Sample data in csv file:

tconst_titles,titleType,primaryTitle,originalTitle,isAdult,startYear,endYear,runtimeMinutes

```
tt1,short,Carmencita,Carmencita,0,1894,0000,1
tt2,short,Le clown et ses chiens,chiens,0,1892,0000,5
tt3,short,Pauvre Pierrot,Pauvre Pierrot,0,1892,0000,4
```

## My Code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class populate { 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IMDB","root","user");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = 
        "load data local infile 'titles.csv' \n" +
        "   replace \n" +
        "   into table Titles \n" +
        "   columns terminated by '\\t' \n" +
        "   ignore 1 lines";
    stmt.execute(sql);
      }
}
```

Comment: As error message says, **Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns** Your database table may have more than 8 columns or may be less data for the first row.

Comment: Add MySQL table structure

Comment: Shouldn't it be `columns terminated by ','` as you have csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your java code. You are separating by `\t`(tab) instead of `,`:

```
"   columns terminated by '\\t' \n" +
```

This line should be:

```
"   columns terminated by ',' \n" +
```

If you want to separate columns by `\t` you can change your csv file data to like below:

```
tt1 short   Carmencita  Carmencita  0   1894    0000    1
tt3 short   Pauvre_Pierrot  Pauvre_Pierrot  0   1892    0000    4
tt4 short   Pauvre_Pierrot  Pauvre_Pierrot  0   1892    0000    4
```

By the way, **csv** meaning **Comma Separated Values**.

Comment: Thank you. That removed the error message. However, I am getting the following error message when running my code after the correction. 

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1894' for column 'startYear' at row 1.

I have declared 'starYear' as a 'DATE' when creating the table. Any idea why it is saying that?

Comment: @user8929822 Because the value not within the proper format to match with the date type. try adding month and date also. As a example `1894-1-1`

Comment: well, its suppose to be a year, so I would like to keep it that way. anyways, thanks. I will open a new thread for the question.